# how to complete user defined class methods using javacomplete

Tags: java, editor, vim

I am working under Mac OS X 10.7. I got *javacomplete* working with the help of *pathogen*, but it **only** completes JDK classes, not the classes I've created. When trying to omni-complete one of my objects I'm getting 'Pattern not found'. Is this really limited to JDK classes? If not, can anybody describe their config.

BTW, I've tried created *ctags* but it didn't work with javacomplete either. However, *ctrl-x ctrl-]* works fine with ctags created.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the class path for your sources.

From the javacomplete documentation:

```
3. Set classpath using the following function: >
    javacomplete#AddClassPath('jarfile_or_classes_path')
    javacomplete#DelClassPath('jarfile_or_classes_path')
    javacomplete#SetClassPath('semicolon_separated_string')

    Another two variables will be used if they are existing:
        |g:java_classpath|  global classpath
        |b:classpath|       associated with current buffer
```

I have added the following to my *.vimrc* to auto-complete android projects:

```
if filereadable('AndroidManifest.xml')
    call javacomplete#SetClassPath('/home/tidbeck/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-17/android.jar:libs/android-support-v4.jar:bin/classes')
    call javacomplete#SetSourcePath('src')
endif
```

Two things that I noticed:

- `javacomplete#AddClassPath` does not support `jar` files even though the docs say so
- I had to remove my tags file to get completion to working

Answer (score 0):

I've used javacomplete plugin along with supertab and i found that the easiet way to enable method completion is by using another plugin called [easytags.vim](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags) that automatically creates tags as you compile your classes. From memory it did provide user defined Class and method completion.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the vim plugin you have to add these lines into `.vimrc`:

```
" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")
  autocmd Filetype java setlocal omnifunc=javacomplete#Complete
endif
```

I am, too, was unable to get it working with an existing tags file (created by `ctags`). As mentioned, one workaround is to unset the vim option `tags` inside `.vimrc`. But this was not an option for me.
I just manipulated `javacomplete.vim` to "ignore" the tags file.

Patch follows:

```
--- autoload/javacomplete.vim   2011-01-30 21:33:46.000000000 +0100
+++ /home/kndl/.vim/autoload/javacomplete.vim   2015-02-12 20:46:48.227465321 +0100
@@ -2510,7 +2510,8 @@
 fu! s:GetClassInfoFromSource(class, filename)
   let ci = {}
   if len(tagfiles()) > 0
-    let ci = s:DoGetClassInfoFromTags(a:class)
+    " kndl: Deactivate ctags feature as this does not work. It seems that I am unable to build an accepted tags file.
+    "let ci = s:DoGetClassInfoFromTags(a:class)
   endif

   if empty(ci)
```